Athena extract value from nested json with dynamic key
I have following json
{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}

With following query I am able to get Tier value
select  json_extract(
            '{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}'
        , '$.Tier'
    )

Similar way I am trying to get Max and Min value, but it is not working, It returns blank
select  json_extract(
            '{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}'
        , '$.Max'
    )

All and 1 is dynamic value, it could be different
What I am doing wrong
Thanks,

$.Tier.All.1.Max !?

@luk2302, All and 1 is dynamic value, it could be different

What I am doing wrong
'$.Max' is a JSON Path (RFC) expression. It represents path in your JSON, in this case it will look for Max property in the root object, which clearly is not present.

The root node identifier $ refers to the root node of the query
argument, i.e., to the argument as a whole.

json_extract in Presto/Trino has quite minimal support for JSON path expressions. You have 2 main options here (as described in my previous answer) - casting to maps or using json_query. For example if you have a single key:
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(
            '{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}'
        , 'lax $.Tier.*.*.Max' 
    );

Output
  _col0
----------
 "100000"
(1 row)

For multiple values 'lax $.Tier.*.*.Max' with array wrapper can be used.
